# Meteor template.find is undefined

Tags: javascript, events, templates, meteor

I am trying to use [`template.find`](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_find) to make my life easier.

But in the javascript console I get: `undefined is not a function`

Here's what I have. It is getting tripped up on `template.find(...)`

```
  Template.superuserHUD.events = 
  {
    'click input.new_device': function (template) {
      var id = template.find(".new_device_id").value;
      Device_IPs.insert({ID: id, IP: "Not Connected"});
    }
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: instead of finding the element that matches the selector, you should directly retrieve the value-text of element using `.getElementById()` method

Comment: Hi user1191551, you've asked 5 questions but not accepted any answers to them. It's considered common courtesy here to accept answers you find useful. It will also improve the quality of answers given to your future questions. Thanks!

Comment: thanks Rahul. It appears that I seem to have 2 different accounts because I have definitely answered and accepted more answers than this account shows...

Answer (score 16):

The Event handler function receives two arguments: `event`, an object with information about the event, and `template`, a template instance for the template where the handler is defined.

The second parameter is optional, but it needs to be received in handler when you want to use template instance functions like `find()`, `findAll()`, `firstNode()` and `lastNode()`.

So, to use the `template.find()` in your event handler, you need to pass both the arguments as:

```
'click input.new_device': function (event, template) {
     // your event handling code
  }
```

Comment: hmm. I tried this:
'click input.new_device': function (event, template) {
    var id = this.find(".new_device_id").value;
    console.log(id)
}
but it still didnt work. still undefined...

And this is the html: ID:<input type="text" class="new_device_id">
 <input type="button" class="new_device" value="add" />

Comment: You are still doing it wrong, in the `'click input.new_device'` the `this` will refer to current `window` object, *not* the `template` you are trying to work with. So, obviously `this.find()` will return `undefined`. So, you *must write* `template.find()` instead of `this.find()`.

Answer (score 5):

use a second arugment please like

```
Template.superuserHUD.events
    'click input.new_device': (event, template) ->
        options =
              id: template.find('.new_device_id').value
              IP: 'Not Connected'
        Device_IPs.insert options
```

and sometimes use template itself like

```
Template.superuserHUD.events
    event: (event, template) ->
        @find('.new_device_id').value
```

Here's the same in javascript for the coffee illiterate...

```
Template.superuserHUD.events({
  'click input.new_device': function(event, template) {
    var options;
    options = {
      id: template.find('.new_device_id').value,
      IP: 'Not Connected'
    };
    return Device_IPs.insert(options);
  }
});
```

---

```
Template.superuserHUD.events({
  event: function(event, template) {
    return this.find('.new_device_id').value;
  }
});
```

Comment: sorry, but i completely dont understand this syntax. is this javascript? I have never seen "->"