# Template reuse in meteor

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I'm trying to reuse some control elements in my Meteor app.  I'd like the following two templates to toggle visibility and submission of different forms.

```
<template name='addControl'>
  <img class='add' src='/images/icon-plus.png' />
</template>

<template name='okCancelControl'>
  <img class='submit' src='/images/icon-submit.png' />
  <img class='cancel' src='/images/icon-cancel.png' />
</template>
```

I'll call these templates in another:

```
<template name='insectForm'>
  {{#if editing}}
    <!-- form elements -->
    {{> okCancelControl}}
  {{else}}
    {{> addControl}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

`editing` is a `Session` boolean.

**What's a good way to wire up the controls to show, hide and "submit" the form?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is finding the addInsect template (where the data is) from the control templates (where the "submit" event fires).  Here's what I did:

First, the controls:

```
<template name='addControl'>
  <section class='controls'>
    <span class="add icon-plus"></span>
  </section>
</template>

<template name='okCancelControl'>
  <section class='controls'>
    <span class="submit icon-publish"></span>
    <span class="cancel icon-cancel"></span>
  </section>
</template>
```

Now the javascripts.  They simply invoke a callback when clicked.

```
Template.addControl.events({
  'click .add': function(event, template) {
    if (this.add != null) {
      this.add(event, template);
    }
  }
});

Template.okCancelControl.events({
  'click .cancel': function(event, template) {
    if (this.cancel != null) {
      this.cancel(event, template);
    }
  },
  'click .submit': function(event, template) {
    if (this.submit != null) {
      this.submit(event, template);
    }
  }
});
```

I then connected the callbacks using handlebars' `#with` block helper.

```
<template name='addInsect'>
  {{#with controlCallbacks}}
    {{#if addingInsect}}
      <section class='form'>
        {{> insectErrors}}
        <label for='scientificName'>Scientific Name <input type='text' id='scientificName' /></label>
        <label for='commonName'>Common Name <input type='text' id='commonName' /></label>
        {{> okCancelControl}}
      </section>
    {{else}}
      {{> addControl}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

And the corresponding javascript that creates the callbacks relevant to this form.

```
Session.set('addingInsect', false);

Template.addInsect.controlCallbacks = {
  add: function() {
    Session.set('addingInsect', true);
    Session.set('addInsectErrors', null);
  },
  cancel: function() {
    Session.set('addingInsect', false);
    Session.set('addInsectErrors', null);
  },
  submit: function() {
    var attrs, errors;
    attrs = {
      commonName: DomUtils.find(document, 'input#commonName').value,
      scientificName: DomUtils.find(document, 'input#scientificName').value
    };
    errors = Insects.validate(attrs);
    Session.set('addInsectErrors', errors);
    if (errors == null) {
      Session.set('addingInsect', false);
      Meteor.call('newInsect', attrs);
    }
  }
};

Template.addInsect.addingInsect = function() {
  Session.get('addingInsect');
};

Template.addInsect.events = {
  'keyup #scientificName, keyup #commonName': function(event, template) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      this.submit();
    }
  }
};
```

In the submit callback I had to use `DomUtils.find` rather than `template.find` because `template` is an instance of okCancelControl, not addInsect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Session` for this. You Just need a template helper that returns a `boolean` flag that indicates whether you are editing the form fields. And manipulate the DOM based on the Session value set by this template helper.

Assume you have one text input, now when you are entering text in it, set the Session flag as `true`. This will trigger the helper to return true `flag`, Based on that, one of your two templates will be rendered in the DOM.

The `isEditing` is the helper that triggers whenever you change the Session value. 
This helper function is the main part here, it returns true/false based on the session value you have set.

```
 Template.insectForm.isEditing = function(){
    if(Session.get('isEditing')){
     return true;
    }
    else{
     return false;
    }
 }
```

Remember to set the Session to `false` at the start-up as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Session.set('isEditing', false);
})
```

This will render the default `add template` in the html, Now when you click on ADD, you need to display another template, for that, set Session to true as:

```
'click .add' : function(){
    Session.set('isEditing', true);
}
```

Accordingly when you click on CANCEL, set the session to `false`, this will make the `isEditing` to return `false` and the default `add template` will be displayed.

So your complete html will look something like this:

```
<template name='insectForm'>    
  {{#if isEditing}}
    <!-- form elements -->
    <input type="text" id="text" value="">
    {{> okCancelControl}}
  {{else}}
    {{> addControl}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name='addControl'>
  <img class='add' src='/images/icon-plus.png' />
</template>

<template name='okCancelControl'>
  <img class='submit' src='/images/icon-submit.png' />
  <img class='cancel' src='/images/icon-cancel.png' />
</template>
```

**[UPDATE]**

To get the instance of the template, you'll need to pass the additional parameter in the event handler that represents the template.

So update your event handler as:

```
Template.insectForm.events = {
   'click .submit' : function(event, template){
      //your event handling code
   }
}
```

The parameter `template` is the instance of the template from which the event originates.

Note that, although the event fires form the image that is inside the `okCancelControl` template, the parameter will still contain the instance of the `insectForm` template. This is because we are calling the event handler as `Template.insectForm.events = {}` .

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931196/meteor-template-find-is-undefined/13945912#13945912) for template instances.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. When a user clicks on the `icom-submit` image the event fires inside the `okCancelControl` template.  I need a way to get an instance of the `insectForm` template so I can insert the record.

Comment: @DeanBrundage. See the updated answer. but may I know why you are using instances for inserting records ??

Comment: The click happens on the control template. From there can I look into the insectForm tenplate? I'm flowing some examples for insertion. Watch for an event, gather user input, insert. In my case the event and input are in different templates.

Comment: Or is there a better way to gather the input values than using the find method on the template instance?

Comment: Yes, *there is* a better way to gather input values while submitting forms, why not simply use `getElementById()`, `getElementByTagName()`, `getElementByClassName()`?. These are a lot better than `template.find()`

Comment: Great, thanks. All the examples I see use `template.find()` so I was just going with that.