# Meteor row result expand on click

Tags: templates, meteor, expand

I want to make each result expandable to show extra details or edit form for the specific item.

Looking for similar questions I found this
[Template reuse in meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098662/template-reuse-in-meteor)

The problem I am having is using that would expand every result if I expand one :(

Here's the code I'm using atm:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  Session.set('edit', false); 
});


Template.editdisplay.events({
  'click .edit' : function(){
    Session.set('edit', true); 
  } 
});

Template.editdisplay.edit = function(){
  if(Session.get('edit')){
    return true; 
  } 
  else{
   return false;
  } 
};
```

HTML:

```
<template name="editdisplay">
  result..
  {{#if edit}}
    {{> editform}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you use one reactive variable to control expanding of every item – what other behavior would you expect? You need to create a separate variable for each template instance. Simplest example:

```
Template.editdisplay.events({
  'click .edit': function(e, t) {
    Session.set('edit-' + t.data._id, true); 
  }, 
});

Template.editdisplay.edit = function() {
  return !!Session.get('edit-' + this._id);
};
```

Comment: It's not working :/ Do I need to add something else to html? like {{#if edit _id}}, didn't think it would be this easy.. ^^ or do I need a edit boolean in the collection?

Comment: I assumed the data context for your template has the `_id` parameter defined, is that true? Try logging `t.data._id` and `this._id` before they are used, are the values correct?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about there, but in my remove function i just use (onclick function) `Collection.remove(this._id);` Think you can do a simple example on how this would work, javascript and html. nothing is working atm, either I open all or none :/

Answer (score 0):

While its not the most elegant solution, you could store the current edited item's id in the session variable, and use something like this:

```
{{#if equals _id editingId}}
  {{> editForm}}
{{/if}}
```

and the js would look like this:

```
Template.editDisplay.events({
  'click .edit':function(event, template)->
     Session.set("editingId", template.data._id);
})

Template.editDisplay.editingId = function(){
  return Session.get("editingId");
}
```

equals is a simple helper:

```
UI.registerHelper("equals" , function(val1, val2){
  return val1 === val2;
})
```

and to avoid issues with live update:

```
Template.editDisplay.created = function(){
  Session.set("editingId");
}
```